# Programmatically change combination of sprites

Tags: c#, sprites, image

I am a total newby to unity and cannot figure out how to achieve the following:

I want to show a picture composed of different sprites. E.g., a pen with four binary features: the pencolor (black or silver), the penshape (ballpen or normalpen), an ornament (blue or orange), and the tintcolor (blue or black).

### My goal:

A function taking a numerical vector as input to specify which of the features/attributes of the pen to show.

- 0,0,0,0 = a black ballpen with blue ornaments and blue
  tint.
- 1,1,1,1 = a  a silver normal pen with orange
  ornaments and black tint.
- ... and all combinations in between.

One constraint: I need to be able to change how many features there are, and how many values they take.

The sprites are stored in a sprite with mode "multiple" and I use unity to create the layers.

What I did so far:

### 1) Define an object holding the feature sprites

To enable changing how many features and feature values there are I created a structure. It has flexible length specifying the number of features. Each feature is sprite array specifying the number and source of the featuer values.

```
// New object class holding all visual feature sprites in hierarchical vectors
[Serializable]
public struct Feature
{
    public string Name;
    public Sprite[] FeatureValues;
}

public Feature[] Features;
```

This allows me to specify how many features, how many different sprites per feature, and to drag and drop the respective sprites onto the associated elements of the Features structure.

[image: unity screenshot]

### 2) Defined a Prefab for the Pen

With the help of [this post on displaying multiple sprites](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72557/how-can-i-get-multiple-sprites-on-a-unity2d-sprite-renderer) I created a prefab with as many layers as there are features of the pen

[image]

### 3. And now ... ?

Based on the first comment I created Sprite Renderers for all sub-elements of the Pen object.

The Pen object is a prefab.

Can anyone help me how to change the values of the sprite?

I am trying this: Based on the link mentioned above I create a new class for Pen objects with some sprite renderers

```
public class Pen : MonoBehaviour {

public SpriteRenderer Tintcolor;
public SpriteRenderer Casecolor;
public SpriteRenderer Ringcolor;
public SpriteRenderer Shape;

public void setTintcolor (Sprite featureImage)
{
    Tintcolor.sprite = featureImage;
}
public void setCasecolor (Sprite featureImage)
{
    Casecolor.sprite = featureImage;
}
public void setRingcolor (Sprite featureImage)
{
    Ringcolor.sprite = featureImage;
}
public void setShape (Sprite featureImage)
{
    Shape.sprite = featureImage;
}
```

}

Then I write a function to change the value of the sprite renderer.

```
// featureCombination is the vector holding the feature values to be displayed   
public void ShowFeatureCombination(int[] featureCombination)
{
    Pen newPen = Instantiate(penPrefab) as Pen; // new Pen object

    newPen.setTintcolor(Features[0].FeatureValues[featureCombination[0]]);  
    newPen.setCasecolor(Features[1].FeatureValues[featureCombination[1]]);
    newPen.setRingcolor(Features[2].FeatureValues[featureCombination[2]]);
    newPen.setShape    (Features[3].FeatureValues[featureCombination[3]]);
}
```

This does not work so far.

And it requires to manually specify the spriteRenderers, which i need to have automatically done based on the number of different features that I enter in the Feature structure.

Comment: each part of the pen which is visible must have a sprite renderer. Just attach it in the editor. What you will need to do is having a script with references of the 4 children and change sprites acording to parameters

Comment: Thank you. I created a sprite renderer, but need help with how to script this (I updated the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a script attached to your Pen object.

Inside this script you have references (wether public or just visible in editor) where you drag the children via editor.

```
class YourPenScript {
    public GameObject Tint;
    public GameObject Case;
    public GameObject Ring;
    public GameObject Shape;

    private SpriteRenderer sr_tint;
    private SpriteRenderer sr_case;
    private SpriteRenderer sr_ring;
    private SpriteRenderer sr_shape;

    void Awake(){
        sr_tint = Tint.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        sr_case = Case.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        sr_ring = Ring.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        sr_shape = Shape.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    public void ShowFeatureCombination(int[] featureCombination){
        /* here you should apply your logic to pick features and apply sprites*/
    }
}
```

In this way you have a class with references to desired components. Now you can apply your logic to pick sprites from the features.

**EDIT**:

To fit your needs of dynamic feature number you have to create at runtime al the gameobjects needed by your pen.

consider having an initialization function like

```
public void Initialize(int[] featureCombination){
    foreach(Transform t in newPen.transform){
        if(t!=newPen.transform) Destroy(t.gameObject);
    }
    ShowFeatureCombination(featureCombination);
}
```

with consequent change to your function

```
public void ShowFeatureCombination(int[] featureCombination)
{
    Pen newPen = Instantiate(penPrefab) as Pen; // Move this to awake and make newPen a class variable

    for(var i = 0; i < featureCombination.Length; i++){
        GameObject f = new GameObject();
        f.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        //insert your logic to apply sprite
        /*maybe f.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = _spriteRenderers[i]; ?*/
        f.transform.parent = newPen.transform;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes sense!! To make the number of sprite renderers flexible, I ended up getting the sprite renderer component from all children of the pen object by using `private SpriteRenderer[] _spriteRenderers;` and `_spriteRenderers = GetComponentsInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();`

Comment: doesn't your pen have 4 children? each one can have only 1 spriteRenderer. Tint, Case, Ring, Shape in your case. For what I understood you should have all the sprite renderers and in your logic function apply sprites only where there is a feature. The remaining will have a null sprite. Be sure to set the alpha to 0 where the sprite is null.

Comment: Yes, this pen has 4 children. Remember that in my original question I said I need the number of features (pen children) to be flexible. The object in my next scene may have 3 or 5 children (features); and I want to avoid having to recode that part by hand.

Comment: So in this way you shouldn't be able to change your feature elements. I edited my answer with the gameobject creation part. Consider that this code is not tested. may contain errors